# Check Google Sheet if value already existes before inserting data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Hello Guys**
So i have multible input fields, where a user types words and the he has to select categories in which his typed word should get inserted. Here you can see it. It is in German sorry.
[image: Input]
The 2 Input fields are "Eingabe Keyword" and "Eingabe Suchvolumen" 
After the user has filld out both input fields and selected a "Ketegorie" and a "Wortart" he clicks the arrow and i check if everything if filled out and nothing is empty. 
After that i write the Input in a table depending on what the user selects. 
Here is an example on how 2 of these looks 
[image: Example Table]

But before i write the data into one of these small tables i would like to check if it already exists. If yes i would create a ui alert to let a person know that that word is already in the table. 
The question is how do i sort through all of those rows and check if the exact word already is there?
Any help or information you guys could provide to me would be really helpfull. 
If somethign is badly explained please let me know. English is not my main language so i am sorry if it is not great.

**Thx again**

Comment: So basically you want to search if a word is in the `Keyword` columns, right?

Comment: Yes i want to search if the word someone wants to insert is already in one of `keyword` collums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search a value in a range you may use the following:

```js
function hasValue(range, value) {
  return range.getValues().flat().includes(value)
}
```

This then can be called however you like. `range` is the range to search in (in your case the column) and the value is self explanatory.
here an example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A3:A')
  const result = hasValue(range, 'example')
  console.log(result)
}
```

### Function rundown

1. `range.getValues()` get all the values on the range.
2. `flat()` flattens the 2D array into a simple array with all the values.
3. `includes(value)` returns if the array contains the value.

### References

- [Range.getValues() (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.prototype.flat() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Array.prototype.includes() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)